# mysql lite database cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova

i have a problem with my mysql lite database in my cordova project.
I try to test it on my htc one x+ with android version 4.2.2 but nothing works.
The javascript alerts and the database code both doesn't work on the phone and the emulator. The weird thing is that the code for the back button works but the alert in this code not. Maybe you can find the reason? Here comes the code.

```
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        function onBackButton() {
            console.log("Test");
            alert("Back Button works!");
            window.location = "bearbeiten.html";
        }
        function onLoad() {
            alert("onLoad method works!");
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReadyBb, false);
        }
        function onDeviceReadyBb(){
            document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackButton, false);
        }
        function saveTopic(){
            //Load the device API libraries 
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        }// Device APIs are now available
        function onDeviceReady() {
            //Create database object
            var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "EasyLearning", 200000);
            db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
        }
        //Create database table "topics"
        function populateDB(tx){
            var text = document.getElementById("t1").value;
            alert(text+" is saved in database!");
            var abfrage = tx.executeSql('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM themen WHERE thema ='+text+');
            if(abfrage == 1)
            {
                alert("topic is alredy existing!");
            }
            else{
                alert("New topic will be saved...")
                tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS themen (themennr INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT, thema VARCHAR(10000)');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO themen(thema) VALUES ('+text+')');
            }
        }
        //Shows error if the query is wrong
        function errorCB(tx, err) {
            alert("Error processing SQL: "+err);
        }
        //Shows successful message if it works
        function successCB() {
            alert("Thema erfolgreich gespeichert!");
        }
        </script>
```

Comment: that's just a bunch of function definitions. you don't seem to ever CALL those functions.

Answer (score 1):

First of all it isn't SQLite, it's WebSQL that you are using.

There was some problem with your code that I changed the structure of it and did it in a best practice way recommended by cordova docs, and I hope your problem will be solved by taking a look at it :

```
    var app = {
            initialize: function() {
            this.bindEvents();
        },
        bindEvents: function(){

            document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
            document.addEventListener('backbutton', this.onBackButton, false);

        },
        onBackButton: function(){
            console.log("Test");
            alert("Back Button works!");
            window.location = "bearbeiten.html";
        },
        onDeviceReady: function() {
            var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "EasyLearning", 200000);
            db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);

        },
        populateDB: function(tx){
           var text = document.getElementById("t1").value;
           alert(text+" is saved in database!");
           var abfrage = tx.executeSql('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM themen WHERE thema ='+text+');
           if(abfrage == 1)
           {
               alert("topic is alredy existing!");
           }
           else{
               alert("New topic will be saved...")
               tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS themen (themennr INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT, thema VARCHAR(10000)');
               tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO themen(thema) VALUES ('+text+')');
           }
        },
        errorCB: function(tx, err) {
            alert("Error processing SQL: "+err);
        },
        //Shows successful message if it works
        successCB: function() {
            alert("Thema erfolgreich gespeichert!");
        }
    }
    app.initialize();
```

Note that I didn't change the body of your functions, I just wrote them in the way that it will be executed.
Don't forget to use your browser console, to debug the code before testing on mobile device.